# Unable to forward $_GET variable target PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, get, dynamic-linking

I am working on homework assignment that requires making of a simple news site with the ability to list news from different categories, to allow logged in users to comment articles and delete them.

I managed to do all of the mentioned except deletion. I get this error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:......\delete.php on line 4".

Here is my **show_comments.php** file code:

```
<?php
require_once("konektor.php");

$article_id = $_GET['id'];

$qCommentShow = "
SELECT 
`komentari`.`id` as `kom_id`,
`komentari`.`komentar`,
`komentari`.`korisnik_id`,
`komentari`.`sajt_id`,

`korisnici`.`username`

FROM `komentari`, `korisnici` WHERE `sajt_id` = $article_id 
GROUP BY `komentari`.`id`
ORDER BY `komentari`.`id` DESC ";

$komentarPrikazi = $konektor->query($qCommentShow);

echo "<h3>Komentari korisnika</h3>";

$sviKomentari = $komentarPrikazi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach($sviKomentari as $b){

echo "<div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
<p>Ime: ". $b->username ."</p><p>Komentar:</p><textarea> ". $b->komentar ."</textarea><br>
</div>";
echo "<a href ='index.php?opcija=delete&id=". $b->kom_id ."'>Izbrisi komentar</a>";
echo "<hr>";

}?>
```

and my **delete.php** file code:

```
<?php
require_once("konektor.php")
if (isset($_GET['id'])){

$qBrisi = "
DELETE FROM `komentari` WHERE `id` = '" .$_GET['id']. "'; AND `korisnik_id`  = 
'" .$_SESSION['id']. "';
";

$komentarBrisi= $konektor->query($qBrisi)
}
else {
echo "error";
include ("location: kategorije.php");
}

?>
```

If required, I can also post my **category.php** code where I list all the categories with established dynamic paging.

I have tried looking around the internet what I could be doing wrong but everywhere I checked, the code is almost identical to mine so I am really scratching my head here what I am doing wrong.

P.S I know my code is still unfinished and vulnerable to attacks but right now, I have to make a really basic and functional version of the site.

Comment: missing a semi colon(;) after your require_once in Delete.php

Comment: This is a prime example of why you should be using an IDE to develop with. Debugging this type of stuff is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `;` on line 4 in delete.php :

```
require_once("konektor.php")
```

Comment: *Sigh*, well that's what happens when you are coding for 7 hrs non stop in notepad++. Thank you so much for pointing me the foolish mistake i made! Now I can easily finish my project :)